# Ruby on Rails: link_to is missing part of URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm new to ruby on rails and I have a question concerning `link_to`.
I have for example a link_to like this:

```
<%= link_to 'User...', {:controller => 'users', :action => 'userManagement'} %>
```

which results like this:

```
<a href="/users/userManagement">User...</a>
```

which works fine in the development environment.

But in my production environment I have an URL-rewrite before, which points to my rails server:

https://my-production-url/subdirectory

To get the link_to from above working, I need to have the `subdirectory` also in the path:

```
<a href="subdirectory/users/userManagement">User...</a>
```

Is it possible to configure this somewhere only for production?

I hope you understand what I mean and sorry for my bad english!

Thanks for reading,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

You would do this by setting `action_controller.relative_url_root`.

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # ...
  config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/sub_directory'
end
```

You would place this in `/config/environments/production.rb`.

On a side note your route is very idiosyncratic. Normally the routes for an admin section would look like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin, module: :admin do
    resources :users
  end
end
```

This would create the following routes (`$ rake routes`):

```
         Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
    admin_users GET    /admin/users(.:format)          admin/users#index
                POST   /admin/users(.:format)          admin/users#create
 new_admin_user GET    /admin/users/new(.:format)      admin/users#new
edit_admin_user GET    /admin/users/:id/edit(.:format) admin/users#edit
     admin_user GET    /admin/users/:id(.:format)      admin/users#show
                PATCH  /admin/users/:id(.:format)      admin/users#update
                PUT    /admin/users/:id(.:format)      admin/users#update
                DELETE /admin/users/:id(.:format)      admin/users#destroy
```

Think resources - not pages. And don't use `camelCase` in your routes or method names or you will never be allowed to sit at the cool kids table.

Comment: Hi max!
Thanks for your answer, but this has no effect! :-(
I still get the URL without 'sub_directory'.

Comment: It does - I'm guessing you did not restart the server or set it properly. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html